# Case Statement Based on 3 tables MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to write a case statement based on the 3 tables such that if column 1 from table A is blank then look for column 2 from table B and if column 2 is blank then look for Column 3 from table C

```
TableA
Column 1a   Column 1
 1           

TableB
Column 1a   Column 2
 1           

TableC
Column 1a  Column 3
     1           A
```

If I had table A and B i.e. two table I would have written something like:-

```
Case when Column A = '' or Column A is null then Column B
else Column A
from tableA a 
Left join TableB b on a.column 1a = b.column 1a
```

But I am not sure how to include 3 columns in case statement. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I think it will be easier if you turn it around: `case when columnA <> '' and columnA is not null than columnA etc.`

Comment: can you sort your column names out as it's unclear as it stands. you have Column A in your case yet no Column A in your definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`coalesce()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) with [**`nullif()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) like so:

```
select 
    a.Column1a
  , Value = coalesce(nullif(a.Column1,''),nullif(b.Column2,''),c.Column3)
from TableA a
  left join TableB b
    on a.Column1a = b.Column1a
  left join TableC c
    on a.Column1a = c.Column1a
```

`coalesce()` will return the first non `null` value from the parameters, and `nullif(...,'')` will return `null` instead of an empty string `''`.

Which is equivalent to:

```
select 
    a.Column1a
  , Value = case when a.Column1 is not null and a.Column1 <> '' then a.Column1
                 when b.Column2 is not null and b.Column2 <> '' then b.Column2
                 else c.Column3
                 end
from TableA a
  left join TableB b
    on a.Column1a = b.Column1a
  left join TableC c
    on a.Column1a = c.Column1a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest your `CASE` statements like so:

```
CASE
    WHEN ColumnA = '' OR ColumnA IS NULL
       THEN
           CASE
               WHEN ColumnB = '' OR ColumnB IS NULL
                  THEN ColumnC
               ELSE ColumnB
           END
   ELSE ColumnA
END
```